# What does >... mean in vim and how to substitute a single whitespace for it?

Tags: text-processing, vim

I know that when `:set list` is used whitespace is shown as `.`. But what does it mean when a whitespace symbol is preceded by `>`, e.g. `>.`, `>..`, or `>...`?
And how do I remove it and leave only one single whitespace `.` behind?

It's a bit hard to give a good example but the whitespace that is included with `>..` feels like chewing gum; meaning if you add more whitespace it will crush other words closer together before moving the whole line to the right:

```
Long    long    time    ago it  began.
```

Comment: Thanks! It's `<^I>` / `Hex 09` / `Octal 011`. Whatever that is.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a `TAB`.

Comment: Do you want to post it as a short answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like if it's a tab. You can confirm this by placing your cursor on it and press `ga` in normal mode. If it displays

```
<^I>  9,  Hex 09,  Octal 011
```

then it's a tab. A space looks like this:

```
< >  32,  Hex 20,  Octal 040
```

To change each tab to a single space:

```
%s/\t/ /g
```